# Is there a way to specify a Tailwind breakpoint once and all the CSS under it get applied to it

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

The way responsive design is made possible in Tailwind as per my knowledge is - 
`<div className="sm: flex sm: flex-row sm: items-center"></div>`

It becomes tedious to constantly type out the `sm:` breakpoint every time I need to specify a new CSS rule.

I was looking for something like this - 
`<div className="sm: (flex flex-row items-center)"></div>` 
Where I specify the `sm` once and everything else gets applied under this breakpoint. It also makes it much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

someone has already asked the same question on github, check out this [discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/8337#discussioncomment-4032611)